# Javascript pending promises returns promise despite resolved data

Tags: javascript, promise, axios

I have a function which resolves in the first then:

```
var a_p = sc.getAllPatientData()
                      .then(res => {
                        console.log(res) // logs {data:array[4]}
                        return res}).then(res=>{return res.data})
                      .catch(error => {console.log(error)});
```

But the `var a_p` returns a pending promise. I do not know how to resolve this 
to extract the data. I would like to make it return the `{data:array[4]}` object seeing as it has clearly fulfilled

Comment: The data is retrieved asynchronously; there is no way to make it behave as if it was retrieved synchronously. You can use `await`, but that's only syntax sugar on top of `.then`.

Comment: how would I use await to make it return the data?

Comment: Use the `await` keyword in front of a Promise

Comment: I have done that... `.then(async res => { await res
                            console.log(res)  return res.data}`but it still returns a promise

Comment: If you do it like that, sure, `async` functions return Promises too

Comment: Could you please point me in the right direction?